# Angular 14 : crypto-js, CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cryptojs

I'm working on an Angular 14 project. I have below code to generate some hashes.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {enc, lib, SHA256} from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CryptoService {

  constructor() {
  }

  static generateCodeVerifier() {
    return this.base64Url(enc.Base64.stringify(lib.WordArray.random(32)));
  }

  static generateCodeChallenge() {
    const codeVerifier = sessionStorage.getItem('codeVerifier');
    return codeVerifier != null ? this.base64Url(SHA256(codeVerifier)) : '';
  }

  private static base64Url(str: any) {
    return str.toString()
    .replace(/=/g, '')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_');
  }
}
```

I get below warning on bundling the app,

> /crypto.service.ts depends on 'crypto-js'. CommonJS or AMD
> dependencies can cause optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

I know I can ignore this by adding the dependancy in angular.json under allowedCommonJsDependencies.

But after reading more about this warning, I do not want to ignore it.

Any suggestions to overcome this issue? I'm open to using other libraries as well.